# Python 3.8 Permission Error when using shutil.move

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python code that will watch a particular folder for any event "modified' and then it copies the rows from source csv file to destination csv file. I'm using Python 3.8 on Windows

After copying the rows, i would like to move the source file to an archive folder and that's when i get the 'Win32 Permission Error'

Can anyone help with this?

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

```
@staticmethod
def on_any_event(event):
    if event.is_directory:
        return None

    elif event.event_type == 'modified':
        # Take any action here when a file is place in the Watch Folder.
        nsrc_file = event.src_path
        dst_file = "C:\\Users\\paramm\\Documents\\Python\\WB_output\\OE_2019.csv"
        archive_folder = "C:\\Users\\paramm\\Documents\\Python\\WB_archive"

        with open(nsrc_file, "r") as f_input, open(dst_file, "a", newline='') as f_output:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

            for row in csv_input:
                csv.writer(f_output).writerows(csv_input)

            shutil.move(nsrc_file, archive_folder)
```

Error:
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Comment: Does moving the `shutil.move()` call outside of the with statement work?

Comment: if i move the shutil.move() outside of the with statement, then i get the following error, Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: <SourceFileName.csv>
  File "C:\Users\paramm\Documents\Python\CSVcopy.py", line 41, in on_any_event
    with open(nsrc_file, "r") as f_input, open(dst_file, "a", newline='') as f_output: